# How to change the color of the values in a Gauge with LiveCharts

Tags: c#, maui, livecharts

In my `NET8` `MAUI` app, I'm using `LiveCharts` to display 2 gauges. The first one is the *[Angular Gauge](https://livecharts.dev/docs/Maui/2.0.0-rc1/samples.pies.angularGauge)* and the other one is the *[Multiple Values Gauge](https://livecharts.dev/docs/Maui/2.0.0-rc1/samples.pies.gauge3)*.

[image]

[image]

For other components on the page, I changed the colour based on the system theme. I can't find a way to change the colour of the values and the external lines (see the arrow in the picture above) or the tick.